# Selenium session handling

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to automatically navigate a webpage. Right now I"m using the Firefox Driver. When the page loads, I go to the login page, enter my credentials, and am sent to the home page. When I try to go to another page in the application, it prompts me to login again, almost as if the cookies have been cleared as I go from page to page.

Is that the default behavior in selenium, and can I change that so that I can maintain a session from page to page? When I manually navigate to the website and move from page to page, it behaves as it should, so there is something going on with selenium, not sure what.

Comment: It should not work like this. Session handling depends on browser, not how you control it. Are you sure you don't have any weird firefox profile in use when running it with Selenium? Does you Selenium framework do some magic with cookies etc?

Comment: Selenium handles session pretty well. There seems to be no reason selenium will log you out if the same scenario works well manually, unless you are doing random stuffs clearing the cookies. It's not Selenium issue as far as I can say.